# Quero usar DISPLAY:FLEX no CSS mas não estou conseguindo?

Tags: html, css

```
<iframe class="OrganizarPosicao"
src="https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6378354762370285568" 
height="525" width="504" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
</iframe>
```

---

```
.OrganizarPosicao{
display:flex;
Justify-content: center;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc quer centralizar?

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito vaga, o que vc precisa exatamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entendo que você quer alinhar o *iframe*, no meio de sua página.

Dessa maneira, você não deve aplicar a propriedade *display* no *iframe*, mas, sim, no elemento pai.

Nesse sentido, a mesma coisa ocorre com o a propriedade *justify*: ela deve ser aplicada no elemento pai do .OrganizarPosicao.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dado isso, poderias fazer algo como esse código:

```css
body {
  background: cyan;
}

.pai {
  width: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.linkedin {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <img class="linkedin" src="https://i.imgur.com/RxZ5rIx.png" alt="flex child">
</div>
```

*Ps: Note que usei uma imagem para substituir seu iframe, assim como a classe .linkedin foi trocada por .OrganizarPosicao.*